# Preg Match issues

Tags: php, preg-match

I've been stuck with a fairly simple `preg_match` for a while and was wondering if someone could help me out.

Here is what im trying to do.

```
$string = 'Sub Total£24.00Shipping£5.95Grand Total£29.95Email:';
$m = preg_match('/Shipping(.*?)\Grand/s', $string, $match);
```

the array `$match` is returning empty and I really cant understand why.

Comment: Try using: `preg_match('/shipping(.+)grand/is', $string, $match)`;

Answer (score 2):

The `\G` token is the "last match" position anchor (like in PERL).

You need to esacape it:
`\\G`

More info:

The anchor \G matches at the position where the previous match ended. During the first match attempt, \G matches at the start of the string in the way \A does.

Source: http://regular-expressions.mobi/continue.html

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you shouldn't have the `\` before `Grand`.  The sequence `\G` must mean something.